# MS-ACCESS Difference between TempVars and TempVar

Tags: ms-access, global-variables, temporary

Maybe I missunterstood the difference between `TempVars` and `TempVar`.

As i know `TempVars` represents the collection of 255 TempVar.

`TempVar` is one of the variable inside the `TempVars` collection.

So if i declare this in a module:

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

Public GlobalTemp As TempVars
Public CurrentUser As TempVar
Public CurrentSecurity As TempVar
Public UserLogin As TempVar
```

`GlobalTemp` is the name of the `TempVars` collection and the others below are its `TempVar` variables?

If that is true, inside an hypothetic Login form i have to use the TempVar in this way?

```
TempVar!CurrentUser.Value = Me.txtUsername.Value
```

Comment: I've never used TempVars but what you describe does not follow examples I viewed. I don't see a TempVar object, only TempVars. The declared variable names are elements of TempVars collection. http://www.iaccessworld.com/how-to-set-temporary-value-tempvars/

Comment: Tried your code and it fails. Not associated with failure but  `.Value` is not needed.

Comment: You are right, `TempVar!CurrentUser.Value = Me.txtUsername.Value` returns an error but i still don't understand the difference between `TempVars` and `TempVar`..

Comment: TempVars is already declared and built in. You really don't want to create your own set of temp vars in a global variable since then you could just declare the global  variable.  And you  can't use your own variables in expressions like you can use the built in tempvars say in sql expressions. So, creating your own global temp var collection defeats the purpose of using temp vars. If you have a un-handled error then all variables including your global tempvars collection will go out of scope - not all that useful. So there is a pre--made and built in tempVars collection you can and should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TempVar to declare a variable as a TempVar type. Then can loop through TempVars collection by iterating the TempVar variable. Example:

```
Sub test()
Dim x As TempVars
Dim y As TempVars
TempVars!x = "ABC"
TempVars!y = "DEF"

Dim z As TempVar
For Each z In TempVars
    Debug.Print z.Name & ";" & z
Next
End Sub
```

MS documentation about TempVar seems to be confusing at best and just plain wrong at worst https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.TempVar.